# div's background-image not shown

Tags: css, image, html, alignment

Dynamically I do the following:

```
'<div><img class="image-blockUI" src="../../images/Edit.gif" /><p class="text-blockUI">Being edited.</p></div>'
```

css:

```
.image-blockUI 
{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.text-blockUI
{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Above code is working (image and text are centered horizontally, image above the text) but now instead of using an image (img) I want to replace it with a background-image for the div so I do below:

```
'<div"><div class="image-blockUI" /><p class="text-blockUI">Being edited.</p></div>'
```

now I replace image-blockUI with this:

```
.image-blockUI 
{
    height: 30px;
    width: 24px;
    background-image: '../../images/Edit.gif';
}
```

In this case, text is displayed and horizontally centered but background-image is not shown. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Keep in mind that file references in CSS are relative to the CSS file, not the HTML document.

Comment: maybe the cause is an incorrect image path? how to do from css to generate the path automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be `background-image: url('../../images/Edit.gif');`

Answer (score 1):

if you use a relative path in a css file, the path is related to the location of the file (.css), so if your css file is not located in the same folder as your original html you need to correct it

Comment: No, in your situation a raw image icon will be displayed instead of no image/icon.,